# Aligning grid lines in R, bReeze package

Tags: r, plot, gridlines

I am trying to get grid lines work properly in the image below. Using the `bReeze` package to plot the power curves of the turbines with:

```
library(bReeze)
pc=pc("Vestas_V90_1.8MW.wtg") 
plot(pc)
```

The output plot is:

[image: Output Vestas v90 power curve]

but assigning grid lines to the plot with the help of:

```
grid()
```

gives the image below:

[image: Output with grid lines]

Any suggestions on how to fix the distorted grid lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't give some arguments (e.g., mar, xlim, ylim), 
`plot(pc)` uses `par(mar = c(5, 5, 1, 5)` and treats data.ranges as `xlim` and `ylim`. By using these properties, you can use `grid()`.

```
pc.data = pc("Vestas_V90_1.8MW.wtg")
plot(pc.data)
par(mar = c(5, 5, 1, 5), new=T)                           # set par() and order to overlay
plot(pc.data[[1]], pc.data[[2]], type="n", ann=F, axes=F) # nothing but setting xy-cordinates
grid(NULL)                                     # here, the same xy-coordinates are reproduced

# If you want to adjust grid lines to right y-axis, use berow code
:
par(mar = c(5, 5, 1, 5), new=T)                   # plot(pc) uses right ylim=c(0,1)
plot(pc.data[[1]], pc.data[[2]], ylim=c(0,1), type="n", ann=F, axes=F)
grid(NULL)                                        # the xy(right)-coordinates are reproduced

# If you plot pc.object having single y-axis, use mar = c(5, 5, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: The code works fine except for the last line, no graph is displayed.