# Align grid() to plot ticks

Tags: r, plot

> When adding ticks to a plot (more ticks than default), how does one get the `grid()` to align the grid to the ticks?

```
plot(1:10,las=1,xaxp  = c(0, 10, 10),xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
grid(lwd=2, nx=10, ny=10)
```

[image]

Tried changed the `xlim` and different numbers for the `nx` arg in grid (number of cells), but the grid simply doesn't line up.

*Related, but doesn't answer question:* [Aligning grid lines in R, bReeze package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994607/aligning-grid-lines-in-r-breeze-package?rq=1)

*Related, and uses workaround:* [Align grid with ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120291/align-grid-with-ticks)

Is the workaround the most efficient option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `abline` to draw grids. You can specify where the grids should be with `h` (for horizontal lines) and `v` (for vertical lines)

```
#Plot
plot(1:10,las=1,xaxp  = c(0, 10, 10),xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
#Add horizontal grid  
abline(h = c(0,2,4,6,8,10), lty = 2, col = "grey")
#Add vertical grid
abline(v = 1:10,  lty = 2, col = "grey")
```

Another workaround is to use `axis` where `tck` value is `1`. With `axis`, you can specify where the grids should be with `at`

```
#Plot
plot(1:10,las=1,xaxp  = c(0, 10, 10),xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))

#Add horizontal grid  
axis(2, at = c(0,2,4,6,8,10), tck = 1, lty = 2, col = "grey", labels = NA)

#Add vertical grid
axis(1, at = 1:10, tck = 1, lty = 2, col = "grey", labels = NA)

#Add box around plot
box()
```

[image]

Comment: And for xts data you can use the following code: abline(v=index(my.xts.data)[endpoints(my.xts.data, "days")]). In this way R makes grid lines for daily time steps. Endpoints can be used for other time steps as well.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that grid is putting nx grid lines in the user space,  but plot is adding 4% extra space on each side. You can take control of this. Adding `xaxs="i", yaxs="i"` to your plot will turn off the extra space.  But then your upper right point will be cut off, so you need to change the xlim and ylim values and change nx to match. Final code is:

```
plot(1:10,las=1,xaxp  = c(0, 10, 10),xlim=c(0,11), ylim=c(0,11),
    xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
grid(lwd=2, nx=11, ny=11)
```

[image: Gridded plot]

Comment: This is a better solution than using abline(). abline() puts the gridlines over the top of the original plot and looks bad.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question

> When adding ticks to a plot (more ticks than default), how does one get the grid() to align the grid to the ticks?

is:

Using function `axis` to obtain the x axis tick locations created by `plot` function in combination with `abline`

Concretely, you substitute the line

```
grid(lwd=2, nx=10, ny=10)
```

by the following three lines

```
x_ticks <- axis(1, 0:10, labels = FALSE)
grid(lwd = 2, ny = NULL, nx = NA)
abline(v = x_ticks, lwd = 2, lty = 3, col = "lightgray")
```

and the result will be

[image]

You can control both x ticks and y ticks and get rid of the `grid` function. In this case the 3 lines would be

```
x_ticks <- axis(1, 0:10, labels = FALSE)
y_ticks <- axis(2, labels = FALSE)
abline(v = x_ticks, h = y_ticks, lwd = 2, lty = 3, col = "lightgray")
```

Comment: Where in the standard ggplot coding would you put something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for the workaround. Because if you look at manual from ?grid, it has this statement,

> "Note: If more fine tuning is required, use ‘abline(h = ., v = .)’
>        directly."