# Aligning grid with limits of plot without abline

Tags: r, plot, grid

How can I align the grid in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2PPM.png) with the data limits of a plot?
My code places the grid in an undesirable fashion. I do not want to use abline as grid seems more professional.

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,1.0), ylim=c(0,1.0), xlab="X", ylab="Y", lwd=3)
grid(nx = 10, ny = 10, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd = par("lwd"))
```

Comment: This question was answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011679/4752675).  The accepted answer uses `abline` but there is another answer that does not use `abline`

Comment: Appreciate your redirection. That answer does not arrange the grid, but the plot. As a result abline provided below looks better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid seems to have other purposes so I could not find a way, but it is very simple with abline. In case you change your mind about abline, here is the way:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,1.0), ylim=c(0,1.0), xlab="X", ylab="Y", lwd=3)
#Add horizontal grid  
abline(h = c(seq(from=0, to=1.0, by=0.1)), lty = "dotted", col = "grey")
#Add vertical grid
abline(v = c(seq(from=0, to=1.0, by=0.1)), lty = "dotted", col = "grey")
```

Comment: Thanks, I look one with grid. I will accept your answer if no-one comes up with an answer near future.